# UI5 responsive layout controls (create responsive CustomListItem)

Tags: css, responsive-design, sapui5

I built a List of CustomListItems in a XML View:

```
<!-- List with CustomListItem (seperate Icon for event) -->     
        <List  class="cTL" id="test-list2" type="Active" headerText="CustomListItems with Icon Control" items="{path : '/products'}">
            <CustomListItem title="boom" counter="3" class="cTL-item" tabindex="1">
                <content>
                    <core:Icon tabindex="2" decorative="false"
                    color="{
                     path: 'price',
                     formatter:'.setPrioColor'
                     }"
                     src="sap-icon://add"></core:Icon>
                    <layout:VerticalLayout class="cTL-text">
                        <layout:content>
                            <Label color="#333333" class="cTL-text-title" text="Orange"></Label>
                            <Text maxLines="1" wrapping="true" class="cTL-text-desc" text="Spain this is a long long long text lalalala onetwothree einzweidreivier Spain this is a long long long text lalalala onetwothree einzweidreivier"></Text>
                        </layout:content>
                    </layout:VerticalLayout>
                </content>
            </CustomListItem>
        </List>
```

and I added some custom css, so that it looks just like a StandardListItem:

```
.cTL .cTL-item.sapMLIB {
                    padding: 0 1rem 0 1rem;
                }
                .cTL .sapUiIcon {
                    font-size: 1.375rem;
                    vertical-align: 80%;
                }
                .cTL .cTL-text {
                    margin: 1rem 0.5rem 0.5rem 1rem;
                }
                .cTL .cTL-text .cTL-text-title.sapMLabel {
                    font-size: 1rem;
                    color: #333333;
                }
                .cTL .cTL-text-desc {
                    color: #666666;
                }
```

[image]

So it works fine if the browser window is fullscreen, BUT: On the Screenshot you can see the List with StandardlistItems above and the CustomListItems below. .. They are not responsive! Which Layout element would you recommend to get it behave like the Standardlistitem (shorten the Text and responsive alignment)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would wrap the content in a `HBox`, and both the icon and the additional layout (which I prefer to be a `VBox` instead of a `VerticalLayout`) in their own, centered `VBox`:

(removed all properties except for the important ones):

```
<List>
    <CustomListItem>
        <content>
            <HBox justifyContent="Start" fitContainer="true">
                <VBox justifyContent="Center">
                    <core:Icon />
                </VBox>
                <VBox justifyContent="Center">
                    <Label />
                    <Text />
                </VBox>
            </HBox>
        </content>
    </CustomListItem>
</List>
```

Comment: "yay" this works fine! just one thing: is it possible so set a special element "fixed"? because the space between the icon and text element should not vary but it does. unfortunately I need to "fit" IE9 too and can not use flexbox at all :-( which one could you recommend for that? thx again

Answer (score 0):

In our team, we replace the VBox and HBox with sap.ui.layout.Grid control. This will allow your layout to be responsive and work in IE9.

https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/explored.html#/sample/sap.ui.layout.sample.GridInfo/preview